# Getting variable name of the variable causing the error in try catch (Java)

Tags: java

Is it possible to return the variable name in java?

If so, how do you do it?

(I am using IntelliJ Community Edition)

EDIT:

Comment below answered about the line of where the error is. I never realize that the function name line was actually for the **exact** line and not for the start of the function.

Comment: The linenumber is buried in the stacktrace `(Line: XXX)`. To get the variablename, at least for NullPointerExceptions, you have to pass `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages` to the JVM

Comment: I have only being receiving the function name and line (not the **exact** line within the function). How do I do the later part?

Comment: EDIT: The function line was actually pointing to the **exact** line within the function. I am such an idiot. I still am curious on how to do the second part though.

Comment: Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
            iae.printStackTrace(); //Get stacktrace
        }
        String s=null;
        System.exit(s.length()); //Boom
    }
}
```

If you run it with `java Test`, you get this output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at Test.main(Test.java:4) //Here, the line
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:9) //Here, the line
```

If you run it with `java -XX:++ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages Test`, you get this output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at Test.main(Test.java:4)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<local1>" is null
    at Test.main(Test.java:9) //You get the line and what is null, here a local with no name
```

If you compile with `javac -g Test.java`, and run it, you even get more output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at Test.main(Test.java:4)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

It doesn't work for other exceptions, but a NPE is thrown quite often.

**-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages will only work in Java 14+!**

Comment: @Michael That's correct. Oops, I forgot that to mention :-)

Comment: Ah shucks. My (uni) project requires me to use Java 8. Ag man. THANK YOU though, I will use this in the future when I eventually use newer Java versions. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Arneev, this has been (and continues to be) a major issue for Java developers literally as long as the language has existed. Sadly, it is not a given you will encounter only up-to-date Java "out in the wild" - even Java 8 is not universally adopted yet.

Comment: Well, you can write Java 8 code and run on Java 14 JVM, and you will still benefit from the above. Since JVMs maintain backwards compatibility, there is very little reason not to upgrade your JVM.

Comment: @Michael, in an enterprise scenario your JVM might be part of your application server. And upgrading application servers is *definitely not* something you do in a coffee break.

Comment: @Taschi thanks for the insight into things. I shall keep it in the mind when I get into the workforce, thank you :)

Comment: @Michael I shall look into this. Thanks :)